# Save file at iphone but archive is corrupted

Tags: ios, download, nsurlconnection

I download a file with NSURLConnection methods, but when I try to save and load data the archive is corrupted

*This is my code any help is appreciated*

```
NSNumber *filesize; 
NSMutableData *data2;

- (void)connection: (NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveResponse: (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response
{

[data2 setLength:0];

    if ([response expectedContentLength] == NSURLResponseUnknownLength) {
        // unknown content size
        filesize = @0;
    }
    else {
        filesize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];

        NSLog(@"%@",filesize);

    }

}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)recievedData {

    [data2 appendData:recievedData];


    if (data2==nil) {
        data2 = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[filesize floatValue]];
    }

    NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[data2 length]]; //MAGIC
    float progress = [resourceLength floatValue] / [filesize floatValue];
    progressBar.progress = progress;


    NSLog(@"%f",progress);

}
```

**AND THIS METHOD CREATE THE FILE. BUT WHEN I TRY TO OPEN THE IPHONE SIMULATOR FOLDER THE ARCHIVE IS CORRUPTED
/Users/astramex19/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/5D2E5AEB-6C27-43A9-9335-207A20A10F13/Documents/db.sqlite**

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {

    NSString *fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/db.sqlite"];

   // BOOL filecreationSuccess = [fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:data2 attributes:nil];

 BOOL filecreationSuccess =   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileName contents:data2 attributes:nil];

    if(filecreationSuccess == NO){
        NSLog(@"Failed to create the file");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse some statements:

```
// this first
if (data2==nil) {
    data2 = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[filesize floatValue]];
}
// Then this
[data2 appendData:recievedData];
```